# Correct version of Eclipse for Android SDK

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, sdk

I'm using Arch Linux (Rolling Release Distro) and after the system upgrade I'm not able to use Android SDK on Eclipse. I believe that its because Eclipse upgraded to 3.7.1. Am I right? Can I use Android SDK on Eclpipse 3.7.1 or do I need a previous version and which one?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirements (http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html) for the Android SDK state:

```
Eclipse IDE

Eclipse 3.5 (Galileo) or greater

Note: Eclipse 3.4 (Ganymede) is no longer supported with the latest version of ADT.
```

Maybe if you gave some more detail about why/how it's not working, we can figure out whats going on.  Do you get any startup errors when opening Eclipse?

Comment: I was using Eclipse 3.6.X. and everything was working fine. After a system upgrade, Eclipse coudn't find the Android SDK. So I guessed that the problem was the version. But I wanted to be sure. I guess I have to downgrade Eclipse in order to get a working Android SDK again.